# AWS Route 53 and Certificate manager

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Because of the confidentiality of the client I can not reveal actual domains. So please bear with me.

1. There is a domain called abc.com already registered outside of AWS.
2. Now I have created a Public Hosted Zone on AWS called xyz.abc.com. It created the list of few ns servers
3. I have created a AWS SSL certificate for domain *.xyz.abc.com
4. I have added this certificate to classic internet facing ELB
5. Now I created a type A alias record set in R53 called bbd.xyz.abc.com pointing to a ELB having SSL certificate ( generated by AWS for domain *.xyz.abc.com)

When I am accessing https://bbd.xyz.abc.com - its not able to resolve but when I am directly giving ELB DNS name it works fine.

My Question is : It is not working because ns (name servers) servers are not added to domain abc.com as abc.com is registered outside of AWS.

Please help

Comment: Your SSL certificate has nothing to do with your problem and muddles the question.

Comment: It's also unclear whether you are using Route 53 here by choice or because you believe it's required.  It is not required.  It's great, but not required.

Answer (score 1):

You must register the Route 53 name servers with your domain registrar. If you do not, then when your browser attempts to resolve your domain name, the DNS system does not know how to get to your Route 53 hosted zone.

The process to do this varies from registrar to registrar. So you'll have to dig into their documentation.

After you've changed the configuration, you may need to wait up to 48 hours for the changes to propagate. Old "bad" resolutions may be cached in various places, so you may need to wait for those to clear.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to *delegate* management of `xyz.abc.com` to Route53's nameservers. This is accomplished by adding the four Route53 nameservers as `NS` records for `xyz.abc.com` in the existing `abc.com` DNS.